# Sequence Number UDF in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera

i have tried this UDF in hive : **UDFRowSequence**. 
But its not generating unique value i.e it is repeating the sequence depending on mappers.  
Suppose i have one file (Having 4 records) availble at HDFS .it will create one mapper for this job and result will be like  
1 
2 
3 
4 
but when there are multiple file (large size) at HDFS Location , Multiple mapper will get created for that job and for each mapper repetitive sequence number will get generated  like below
1 
2 
3 
4 
1 
2 
3 
4 
1 
2 
.

Is there any solution for this so that unique number should be generated for each record

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for `ROW_NUMBER()`.  You can read about it and other "windowing" functions [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics).

**Example:**

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ()
FROM some_database.some_table
```

Answer (score 0):

@GoBrewers14 :- Yes i did try that. 
We tried to use the ROW_NUMBER function ,but when we try to query this on small size data eg.  file containing 500 rows, it’s working perfectly. But when it comes to large size data, query runs for couple of hours and finally fails to generate output .

I have came to know below information regarding this :- 
Generating a sequential order in a distributed processing query is not possible with simple UDFs. This is because the approach will require some centralised entity to keep track of the counter, which will also result in severe inefficiency for distributed queries and is not recommended to apply.

Comment: Queries don't "run for a couple of hours" and then fail because the data is too big.  Thats the whole point.  To have a lot of data.  Assuming the problem is the `ROW_NUMBER()` function and not your code or the number of nodes you have is rather presumptuous

Answer (score 0):

If you want work with multiple mappers and with large dataset, try using this UDF: https://github.com/manojkumarvohra/hive-hilo

It makes use of zookeeper as central repository to maintain state of sequence

Answer (score 0):

Query to generate Sequences. We can use this as Surrogate Key in Dimension table as well.

```sql
WITH TEMP AS
  (SELECT if(max(seq) IS NULL, 0, max(seq)) max_seq
   FROM seq_test)
SELECT col_id,
       col_val,
       row_number() over() + max_seq AS seq
FROM souce_table
INNER JOIN TEMP ON 1 = 1;
```

```
seq_test: Its your target table.
source_table: Its your source.
Seq: Surrogate key / Sequence number / Key column
```